# MongoDB Aggregate pipeline taking 10 minutes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two MongoDB collections: `players` and `stats`.

`players` collection have some data I am interested in, and a field named `username` which is used to reference the `stats` collection through a field on `stats` called `username`.

I have the following aggregate pipeline to get the required data from `players` collection that have data on `stats` collection, as well as few other conditions.

```
[{
        $match: {
            "username": {
                $exists: true, $ne: null, $not: {
                    $regex: "^\\s*$"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "stats",
            localField: "username",
            foreignField: "username",
            as: "stats"
        }
    }, {
        $match: {
            stats: {
                $ne: []
            }
        }
    }, {
        $count: "count"
    }]
```

The problem I am facing is that this does not work on big datasets. When I ran this aggregate pipeline on a dataset of 54K documents in the `players` collection and 15k in the `stats` collection, it takes around 10 minutes to execute which is far from ideal.

What would be a possible enhancements to achieve this task on bigger datasets without taking such a long time?

Things I have also considered, I have tried to do a reverse lookup (from `stats` collection and lookup on `players`), but that did not help. I also tried several pipeline stage modifications (project, pipeline within the match stage, grouping, count) but nothing helped.

EDIT

I have tried indexing fields "username" on both collections and that helped to get it down from 10 minutes to 20-25 seconds, but I would like to bring it down more, what other suggestions would be?

Comment: have you done any indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try indexing your collection and try to create indexes of the frequently queried fields

Comment: Indexing massively helped but its still taking 20-25 seconds, what are other suggestions to bring this down to less time?